# ERROR in Cannot find module 'node-sass'

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, macos-high-sierra

Config: macOS High Sierra, version 10.13.2, node:v8.1.2 npm:5.0.3
When I run npm start in my angularjs project I get this error:

```
ERROR in Cannot find module 'node-sass'
```

After this I run:

```
npm i node-sass
```

Now I get this error:

```
gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
```

Why won't npm install node-sass? How can I install node-sass?

Comment: run ```npm install --save-dev node-sass```

Answer (score 542, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Enjoy!

**Edited to explain the options (from comments):**

--save-dev is used so that your app is able to find the module in local node_modules. --save-dev adds package to devDependencies in package.json. --unsafe--perm is used to run install scripts as root. To avoid sudo, use nvm instead. --unsafe--perm is really not needed as sudo is already mentioned. So the command basically air tights the script to install node-sass at any cost.

Comment: This worked, but if someone could add to the answer on why this worked and the simple `npm install node-sass` did not work it would be instructive.

Comment: All I needed was `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm` and it worked for me because I had EACCES issues.

Comment: all I need to was install node-sass in **dev dependencies** `npm install --save-dev node-sass`

Comment: This worked for me. I started getting this issue when I installed node 12 (as I started a new angular project in Angular 8). My angular 6 app would no longer build and throw the error about node-sass. All fixed :)

Comment: I'm still not clear WHY or HOW this solution works. How does adding to "devDependencies" solve the problem? How will it NOT cause problems when deployed? Side-Note: I'm very new to Angular and front end programming. Any clear explanation would be very useful! Many thanks!

Comment: @AmoghNatu just running `npm install node-sass` will install the node-sass module. Adding `--save-dev` will also add the dependency to `package.json`. Adding `--unsafe-perm` allows npm to download node-sass binary (considered unsafe) directly to your project.

Comment: This is funny, because I had exactly the same issue in the same project in 2 computers, and this solution worked in one computer and didn't work in the other

Comment: Solution worked for me is `npm install node-sass@latest`

Comment: Tried and got: `'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I bet you were running `sudo` on Windows...

Comment: sometimes you may get incompatibility errors while doing this operation - if you do - then follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70281346/node-sass-version-7-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0-5-0-0-6-0-0

Answer (score 116):

1. This error is for node-sass is not present ... to solve this just you want to  run following command

`npm install node-sass`

Comment: add as devDependencies ```npm install --save-dev node-sass```.

Comment: Doesn't help. I've already installed node-sass a dozen times (which wasn't easy), but it still fails. Node-sass is clearly a problem.

Comment: @AshokR Can you please elaborate on exactly WHY adding it as devDependencies solves the problem? How will it NOT fail when deployed to prod?

Answer (score 44):

According to node-sass github page, supported node.js version vary release by release.

https://github.com/sass/node-sass

[image]

Example:
Check the version of node you are running.

```
node -v
-> v12.0.0
```

you need node-sass v4.12+. so you can

```
npm install node-sass@4.12.0
```

or if 4.12.0 is the latest

```
npm install node-sass@latest
```

(`npm install node-sass` will install the latest version in many cases, but remember that it does not always install the latest(in this example 4.12.0) if dependency in package.json is written like ^3.0.0, ~4.11.0)
[What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Lastly, using sudo with npm is not a good practice. Please refer to this article. 
https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92

Comment: this solution worked for me ... I was using older 2010 macbook, osx 10.12, and matching the node-sass version as described here solved it

Comment: "npm install node-sass@4.12.0" - resolved my issue - thanks

Comment: npm install node-sass@4.12.0        Worked for me

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me(Installing the correct version).

Answer (score 28):

Doing `npm uninstall node-sass` and then `npm i node-sass` did not work for me.

Solution worked for me is `npm install --save-dev node-sass`.

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 23):

Run:

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

and it'll work fine.

Comment: Doesn't work fine, sadly. For me (on windows) the problem remains.

Comment: Thanks you for this, I didn't realise node-sass required Pythin somehow, but the rebuild error message made this very clear.

Comment: sass doesn't require python, node-gyp what is requiring python and failing most cases.

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me...

```
sudo npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

Comment: Give some explanation so that it would be easy to understand the solution

Answer (score 7):

**node-sass** is not being installed and it can be one of many reasons

You have not installed it

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev
```

You are having a permissions error

```
sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

You had a memory issue because it tried to make it (build from c code in your platform),this applies to some platforms and node versions

```
node --max_old_space_size=8000 $(which npm) install node-sass --save-dev
```

Your node and npm versions are not compatible,which most probably generated a failure in the build process,

In this case use n or nvm to make sure you have the same version in the new and original environment, the one where it did work, as this is usually by using different versions in different environments

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me. I first uninstall node-sass. Then install it back.

npm uninstall node-sass 
npm install --save-dev node-sass

Answer (score 5):

In my case I also had to perform:

```
npm install sass-loader
```

To fix the problem

Answer (score 5):

It failed for me because I was using the latest version of node (12.7.0) I then had to explicitly install the latest version of `node-sass` with:

`npm install node-sass@4.12.0`

Answer (score 4):

I have fix this problem without installing node-sass by this command:

```
npm install node-sass@4.12.0 --no-save --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score 3):

I checked the Node version in my local machine, which is `v10.11.0`.

Then when I checked my development machine, where the error occurred, it had Node version `V.10.8.0`.

Upgrading Node to `v10.11.0` in my development machine fixed the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is the answer which worked in my case. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One of the cases is the post-install process fails. Right after node-sass is installed, the post-install script will be executed. It requires Python and a C++ builder for that process.
The log 'gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!' maybe because it couldn't find any C++ builder. So try installing Python and any C++ builder then put their directories in environment variables so that npm can find them. (I come from Windows)

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with downloading npm dependencies due to network which you have. try to download the npm dependencies in open network . you won't get any issue. i am also faced this similar issue and resolved finally.

use below commands: npm install (it will download all depedencies)
npm start to start the angular application

Comment: @TinySkillz i think he is mentioning no-proxy networks

Answer (score 2):

`npm install node-sass` will do the job in most of the cases, as it will add missing sass npm dependency module doesn't exist or it will overwrite previous crashed version.

For Mac Users use `sudo` in front of above commands.

On Windows machines `npm rebuild node-sass --force` may not work for some users because it's essentially saying, "please force npm to rebuild the sass node module for me". It will not work because that module doesn't exist.

Whenever you did `npm install` to the initial installation, the sass module did not get installed, which is why this problem occurs.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that a webfilter didn't allow me to download the [node-sass package](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-64_binding.node), when I executed the command

```
npm i
```

After the installation of the Windows Build Tools

```
npm i -g windows-build-tools
```

it build `node-sass` on it's own and now I can use it.

PS: I also installed Python 2.7.17 before, but I don't think that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo npm install node-sass@4.12.0` if your node version is 12.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when installing dependencies in **Angular**. I've tried aforementioned techniques but none of them worked until I've deleted `package-lock.json` which was previously created when running Node **v11**.

Now I'm using Node **v12** so this is how I got resolved.

I repeat if you have `package-lock.json` delete it, file and then install dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

you must install node-sass in dev section of package.json

```
npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
npm install node-sass
```

and it still doesn't work remember to change permission to folder

Answer (score 1):

I have also been facing this error. None of the above methods work for me. Please follow this as it worked for me.

For Installing node-sass in Ubuntu 16 via npm :-

You can install with npm 5.2.0 Version

If you are using nvm :-

```
nvm install 8.2.1
nvm use 8.2.1
npm install node-sass
```

If you are using npm separately then upgrade or downgrade npm version to 5.2.0

```
npm install node-sass
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error while I was using Microsoft Visual Studio Code's integrated git terminal. For some weird reason VS code was not allowing me to install 'node-sass'. Then I used 'Git Bash' (which was installed with git) and ran the following command:
`npm install node-sass`
It worked for me. I don't know why & how it worked. If anyone has any explanation please let me know.

Comment: I suspect it is because you needed to be running as admin

Answer (score 1):

You should try to check the log generated by `npm install`.

I have faced the same issues, and I found the error that python2 is not found in the path (environment variable).

After installing Python, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to latest version of nodeJS solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

npm install --save-dev --unsafe-perm node-sass

This will do magic, you can use it with sudo

Answer (score 1):

Exactly same issue i was also facing and i tried all above answers but could not resolve, Below is the command which fixed my problem.

npm install sass-loader sass webpack --save-dev

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I tried to run a project.
First i uninstalled the current version

```
npm uninstall node-sass
```

Then i reinstalled to the latest version with

```
npm install node-sass
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem by installing **v10.16.10** node version.

Answer (score 0):

I met same issue installing node-sass when I am on Node 12.9.0

Once switching to Node 10.19.0, the issue is gone.

Reference: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2632

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the version  `"node-sass": "4.5.3"`, try updating to the latest version. Such as you could try adding `^` `"node-sass": "^4.5.3"` for the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Use this version for node version v 14

"node-sass": "^5.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall then reinstall Xcode. That fixed the error for me.

Answer (score -3):

What fixed it for me was installing the latest version of node-sass, in this case 4.7.2.

Comment: Install how? In the project or global?

Comment: @lealceldeiro: why would you install node-sass globally? if you have a project with scss files, you should install it in project level. 
for your how to install: all npm packages are installed by running npm install <package name> or using yarn.

Answer (score -3):

just run this command in terminal, it will install latest version of node-sass

`npm install node-sass`

Comment: 3 times negative as not useful and none of them gave a reason. why ?