# Error Cannot find module 'node-sass' when creatingbuild in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i am trying to build apk file of my but i am getting these error

```
[WARN] The pro_id field in .\ionic.config.json has been deprecated.

       Ionic Pro has been renamed to Ionic Appflow! We've copied the value in pro_id to id, but you may want to unset
       the deprecated property: ionic config unset pro_id

> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\sass.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.

        ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android exited with exit code 1.
```

i have tried running few commands In Hope they might solve the issue but it didn't work .i have already deleted node_modules folder multiple time but whenever i run npm install but it didn't solved my issue but i am getting this in result

```
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
(ClCompile target) -> 
  c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling
 source file ..\src\custom_function_bridge.cpp)c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet
': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling source file ..\src\custom_importer_bridge.cpp) [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node
-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling
 source file ..\src\create_string.cpp)c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not
 a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling source file ..\src\binding.cpp) [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxp
roj]
  c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling
 source file ..\src\sass_context_wrapper.cpp) [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling
 source file ..\src\sass_types\boolean.cpp) [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling
 source file ..\src\sass_types\color.cpp) [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling
 source file ..\src\sass_types\error.cpp)c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan.h(834): warning C4996: 'node::MakeCallback': was 
declared deprecated (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\color.cpp) [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.v
cxproj]
  c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling
 source file ..\src\sass_types\factory.cpp)c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': i
s not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\null.cpp) [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build
\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling
 source file ..\src\sass_types\list.cpp)c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is n
ot a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\map.cpp)c:\users\user\.node-gyp\10.15.3\include\node\v8.h(3243): note: see declaration o
f 'v8::Object' (compiling source file ..\src\sass_types\null.cpp) [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj
]
  c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling
 source file ..\src\sass_types\number.cpp) [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]
  c:\users\user\desktop\ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' (compiling
 source file ..\src\sass_types\string.cpp) [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]

    47 Warning(s)
    10 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:57.26
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ridebidder-0f377242b949\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm WARN The package @ionic/app-scripts is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@3.10.1 (node_modules\node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR in Cannot find module 'node-sass'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147896/error-in-cannot-find-module-node-sass)

Comment: remove node_modules and install it again using npm install