# running angular project gives error for node-sass

Tags: node.js, angular, angular7

I am running an angular project in my local environment with versions specified below.

```
npm version : 6.9.0
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
```

and i cannot run project and get the errors below:

```
    ERROR in ./src/assets/styles/style.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/assets/styles/style.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
    Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at Object.sassLoader (..\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72)
    ERROR in ./src/app/modules/shared/components/loader/loader.component.scss
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
    Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at Object.sassLoader (..\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72)
    i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

i have tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling it also

---

```
Delete `package-lock.json` file.
Go to node_module folder and `run rm -rf node_modules`.
Run `npm install`
```

---

```
npm rebuild --force
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

Comment: did you also run `npm install node-sass`?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52581213/795683

Comment: @EstebanGehring yes tried that also ... but not helped ...

Comment: @SainPradeep tried with the link provided ... but this also not worked.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, this solved my problem once

```
npm install node-sass -g
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `npm audit fix` to update your dependencies. I had faced a similar issue and was able to fix by running it.

Comment: @TusharG - Could you post the package.json, and did you try this `npm install --save-dev --unsafe-perm node-sass`?

Comment: @TusharG - Also do check this out https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12746#issuecomment-433337619

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
npm install --save-dev --unsafe-perm node-sas
```

> https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2536
>
> **Credit** https://github.com/xzyfer

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall using npm uninstall and again try to install.