# Problem with node-sass on create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, sass

Before I post this question, I have tried all of the solution offered down below :
[ERROR in Cannot find module 'node-sass'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147896/error-in-cannot-find-module-node-sass)

I use create-react-app to create project1 on Windows 10.

My node version :
node -v
-> v12.16.3

Install node-sass :
    npm install node-sass@latest

App.js :

```
import React from 'react';

import "assets/scss/style.scss";


function App() {
  return (
     <div>Hi World</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> npm start

Error on the browser :
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'assets/scss/style.scss' in 'F:\project1\src'

I'm just wondering why isn't there a simpler and guarentee-to-work way to get this node-sass installed and run. After I searched up for solution on google, it turns out that a lot of people (not only me) are having the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sass/node-sass

You can install node-sass@4.12 according to your node version.

Comment: According to the OP question, s/he already installed node-sass therefore this is unlikely to solve the problem. If you think the issue might be linked to the package version and you want to double-check, maybe a comment would be a better place to ask for further information. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to flow three steps:

1. npm install node-sass
2. change file extension ( .css to .scss )
3. change any import to .scss
4. provide proper path for style.scss file( May I know your style.scss path? )

Comment: That's why i have style.scss (instead of style.css) as I mentioned above.

Comment: May I know your style.scss path?  I think, you are not providing correct path for style.scss file.

Comment: F:\Project1\src\assets\scss\style.scss