# Error: 'node-sass' version 5.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, create-react-app, node-sass

I've created a blank React project, using the command: `npx create-react-app` on npm v7.0.7 and Node.js v15.0.1

Installed:

- React v17.0.1,
- node-sass v5.0.0,

Then I tried to import a blank .scss file to the App component:

#### File *App.js*

```
import './App.scss'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      App
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***It throws an error:***

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/s
ass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/App.scss)
Error: Node Sass version 5.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
```

#### File *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "react-17-node-sass-5",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
 ...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1167, accepted):

**TL;DR**

1. `npm uninstall node-sass`
2. `npm install sass`

Or, if using Yarn

1. `yarn remove node-sass`
2. `yarn add sass`

**Edit3**: yes, another edit. Moving to sass (dart-sass) is the best solution. Previous one included locking node-sass to version 4.x.x, which is 2 years old and lacks newer SCSS features.

---

**Edit2**: sass-loader [v10.0.5](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v10.0.5) fixes it. The problem is you might not be using it as a project dependency, but more as a dependency of your dependencies. CRA uses a fixed version, angular-cli locks to node-sass v4, and so on.

The recommendation for now is: if you're installing just node-sass, check the below workaround (and the note). If you're working on a blank project and you can manage your [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) configuration (not using CRA or a CLI to scaffold your project), install the latest sass-loader.

---

**Edit**: this error comes from [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/898). There is a [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) mismatch since node-sass @latest is v5.0.0 and sass-loader expects ^4.0.0.

There is an open issue on their repository with an associated fix that needs to be reviewed. Until then, refer to the solution below.

---

**Workaround**: don't install node-sass 5.0.0 yet (the major version was just bumped).

Uninstall node-sass

`npm uninstall node-sass`

Then install the latest version (before 5.0)

`npm install node-sass@4.14.1`

---

Note: LibSass (hence node-sass as well) [is deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated) and dart-sass is the recommended implementation. [You can use `sass` instead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass), which is a Node.js distribution of dart-sass compiled to pure JavaScript.

Comment: for some reason `yarn add node-sass@4.14.1` is much quicker

Comment: Looks like they just fixed that in https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/commit/c3e279fb4668fce4c597a6c8cd1d0f2ff8bc95e5 , so you can install sass-loader@10.0.5

Comment: @TylikStec yarn is another package manager, but don't use both in the same project, having two lock files may cause issues in deployment

Comment: @marcin it's funny that you say "they" since the person who posted the answer is the one who fixed it :]

Comment: `yarn remove node-sass` and `yarn add node-sass@4` did it for me.

Comment: On a brand new React project similar to OP, I have "node-sass": "v5.0.0" and "sass-loader": "^10.1.0", but the problem persists. My Node version is 15.3.0. When I uninstall node-sass and re-install @4.14.1, the problem persists since I am using Node version 15.3.0 which expects node-sass version 5.0+.

Comment: I got Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1

Comment: Why does it seem like there is no "right" resolution here?  Who is dragging their feet on moving this forward?

Comment: since it's unsupported we may use ***sass package*** instead

Comment: I tried npm install node-sass@4.14.1 and was met with 'npm ERR! code 1 path ../node-modules/node-sass command failed ... gyp info it worked if it ends with ok ...' and the error just keeps going and going. yarn add worked fine though!

Comment: Im switchin gover to LESS. This is too much for me

Answer (score 106):

The only one reason why you get some error like that, is because your Node.js version is not compatible with your node-sass version.

So, make sure to checkout the documentation at *[node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)*.

Or this image below will be help you in deciding what Node.js version can use the node-sass version.

[image]

**For an example,** if you're using **Node.js version 12** on your Windows system ("maybe"), then you should have to install the **node-sass version 4.12**.

```
npm install node-sass@4.12
```

Yeah, like that. So now you only need to install the node-sass version recommended by the node-sass team with Node.js version installed on your computer.

Comment: With this approach you're locked to v4.x, instead of having the latest version of v4. For example node 12 would be stuck with 4.12 even if it supports 4.14. npm update node-sass would not work unless you used `npm install node-sass@^4.12` which is the same than installing 4.14.1 (latest known version of v4).

Comment: Thank's for your response Nicolas Hevia, but I've been try that code above and you're right, it's can't update that version of node-sass if I'm use `npm install node-sass@4.12`. But I've been try with node-sass 4.14.1 in nodejs 12.18.3 and it's not working. That's why I recomended to use the version what the node-sass team recomended and  I'm not use `^`. Because it will update to the latest version of node-sass 4

Comment: This works in contrast to the other suggestions.

Comment: This works, i had some issues installing node-sadd@4

Comment: but my node version is `v16.9.1` & node-sass `6.0.1` is compatible with that node version

Comment: @Zeeshan Ahmad Khalil: Recommended doesn't mean you should use it. That means you can use something else but something else can cause an error or it might work. But what is suggested usually will work.

Answer (score 62):

Uninstall node-sass:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
```

Use [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) by:

```
npm install -g sass
npm install --save-dev sass
```

Comment: Be careful using this approach. React-scripts uses sass-loader v8, which prefers node-sass to sass (which has some syntax not supported by node-sass). If both are installed and the user worked with sass, this could lead to errors on css compilation.

Comment: And also, be careful with global installs.

Comment: Avoid global installs for project specific dependencies. You can always reference a local dependency with npx example `npx sass` while in the project repo.

Comment: I'm using node v14.15.3 with node-sass 4.14.1 and only the sass approach works. Uninstalling and rebuilding node-sass or upgrading it to 5.x didn't solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: This is the best answer because webpack highly recommend using `Dart Sass`

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 51):

`node-sass` aka *LibSass* is [officially deprecated as of October 26 2020](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated) and instead you should use `sass` aka *Dart Sass*.

For `npm` you could do:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass --save-dev
```

For `yarn` do:

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass
```

Comment: Even after that yarn solution, I get Node Sass version 6.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0.

Comment: @Erik Martines Sanches From the error message it is obvious that node sass was not uninstalled

Comment: @ErikMartinesSanches try to restart your node server after installation.

Comment: this solution works for me

Answer (score 20):

The best solution for me was uninstalling *node-sass*.

`npm uninstall node-sass`

then install sass:

`npm install sass`

For those using [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/):

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass
```

Comment: node-sass is not listed in my package.json even before trying "yarn remove node-sass".

Comment: were you able to fix this? if not maybe you could describe what you've been facing and we can try to work out a solution.

Answer (score 14):

If you happen to use [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) with the default [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) package manager, use the following. It worked for me.

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add node-sass@4.14.1
```

Answer (score 8):

Using npm,

1. `npm uninstall node-sass`
2. `npm install node-sass`
3. change the  `"react-scripts": "4.0.0"` into `"react-scripts": "4.0.3"` in ***package.json*** and save
4. `npm install`
5. `npm start`

or, using yarn -

1. `yarn remove node-sass`
2. `yarn add --dev node-sass`
3. as above
4. `yarn install`
5. `yarn start`

Comment: Confirmed this works with Node 15 and node-sass 5.0.0.

Comment: didnt work Missing binding /Users/giz/code/genesislabs/client/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-83/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 14.x

Comment: Changing react-scripts version helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Edit2 [of Nicolas Hevia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0/64626556#64626556) telling that

> sass-loader v10.0.5 fixes it

I launched this command:

```
npm install sass-loader@^10.0.5 node-sass --save-dev
```

That fixed my issue.

Be aware that I am in a development environment. In other cases, the option `--save-dev` should be removed.

Comment: this answer solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me after adding a particular version of the *node-sass* package (node-sass@4.14.1).

Answer (score 4):

This is version problem. Install the right dependent version:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just switch to [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) since *node-sass* is deprecated now anyway.

In your *package.json* file:

```
"node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.49.9",
```

React still asks for *node-sass* after removing it and replacing it with Sass, so you can alias it like this and now React will use Sass.

Comment: don't underestimate last answer! This belief helped me repeatedly

Answer (score 2):

If the error is

> Error: Node Sass version 5.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0

Step 1: stop the server

Step 2: run commands are `npm uninstall node-sass`

Step 3: check node-sass in `package.json`. If node-sass is available in the file then again run Step 2.

Step 4: `npm install node-sass@4.14.1` <=== run command

Step 5: wait until the command successfully runs.

Step 6: start-server using `npm start`

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue, and here's how I was able to fix it:

Firstly, you have to know which `node-sass` version you are using in your project. Then go upgrade or downgrade your current Node.js version to the compatible version with your current `node-sass` version, you can know that from [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass).

Of course, stop the server, and close your IDE.

So, the best way to upgrade or downgrade the Node.js version, has mentioned above in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66205976/12458449). Then remove the `node_modules`, and `package-lock.json` and install again... You can do it as such:

```
npm cache clean --force

rm -rf /node_modules package-lock.json

npm install

npm audit fix

npm run <your_script_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Small update: In case if you get the below error in regard to node-sass, follow the steps given below.

> code EPERM
> npm ERR! syscall unlink

Steps to solve the issue:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Manually remove .node-sass.DELETE from node_modules
3. open Visual Studio
4. `npm cache verify`
5. `npm install node-sass@4.14.1`

Comment: Re *"Visual Studio"*: Do you mean *"[Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)"*?

Answer (score 1):

Just change version to:
"version": "4.14.1" in your package.json file

Answer (score 1):

Adding sass-loader as as dev-dependency solved this for me.
"devDependencies": { "node-sass": "^6.0.0", "sass-loader": "^11.1.1" }

Answer (score 1):

Delete a **yarn.lock** file in the project
and

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add node-sass
```

Comment: what does the lock file do? why nobody else suggests this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**npm uninstall node-sass**

**npm i sass**

Answer (score 0):

In app.js or wherever the css is being imported, make sure to import css and not scss. The script in package.json will create a css file and that's what should be imported.

```
    "scss": "node-sass --watch -include-path src/scss -o src/css"
```

This script will watch a scss file inside of a folder called scss that is inside src. It will then create an css folder inside src and add a css file inside that folder, this is the file you should import in app.js

To run the script:

```
npm run scss
```

File structure example:
`src/scss/styles.scss`

CSS file created by script:
`src/css/styles.css`

Answer (score 0):

Or else Rebuild your node-sass so that the compatibility does not produce an error.
When the incompatibility between node-sass and node occurs, you will get *typescript errors* .
Do this to achieve node-sass compatibility.

**npm rebuild node-sass**

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to an incompatible version of the sass loader with node-sass.

Add these dependencies at the end of your package.json file.

Note: You can google to check which sass-loader version is compatible with your node-sass version.

"devDependencies": {
"node-sass": "^6.0.1",
"sass-loader": "^10.2.0"
}

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Node Sass is deprecated and you may replace it with Dart Sass:

> Warning: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated. While they will continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely, there are no plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or Sass features. Projects that still use it should move onto Dart Sass.

Source: *[node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)*

The below recipe helped me:

1. Uninstall `node-sass`:

   - npm: `npm uninstall node-sass`
   - yarn: `yarn remove node-sass`
2. Uninstall `sass-loader`:

   - npm: `npm uninstall sass-loader`
   - yarn: `yarn remove sass-loader`
3. Install Dart Sass as a development dependency

   - npm: `npm install sass -dev`
   - yarn: `yarn add sass -dev`

Before building, you should also:

1. Remove the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) directory
2. Remove lock file:

   - npm: Remove `package-lock.json`
   - yarn: Remove `yarn.json`

Answer (score -4):

Steps to resolve this issue:

1. Go to your *node_module* folder and open node-sass modules.
2. In the *package.json* file inside node-sass, change the version from "5.0.0" to "4.14.1".
3. Finally in the package.json at the root of the main project again change node-sass version from "5.0.0" to "4.14.4."