# Can't get node-sass to install

Tags: visual-studio, npm, node-sass

I was having an error that a lot of people were having and thought I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0). Essentially, it is saying that my version of node is incompatible with the version of node-sass. A lot of people were having the same issue, so I was confident that link would help. However, when I run npm install node-sass@4.14.1, I get a different error. I know it is got to be some simple fix, but I can't find it! Does anyone understand what is going on here?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "node scripts/build.js"
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\reaga\\Desktop\\bestconnect-react\\my-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.0.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher 
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location 
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\reaga\\Desktop\\bestconnect-react\\my-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\bestconnect-react\my-app\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Comment: Please try using my answer and let me know it's working.

Answer (score 5):

node-sass v4.x isn't supported on Node 15. Either downgrade your Node version or upgrade to node-sass v5 https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy

Answer (score 0):

Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's windows-build-tools by running npm install -g windows-build-tools from an elevated PowerShell (run as Administrator).

**Note:** Working on windows

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#environment-setup-and-configuration

Answer (score 0):

First install:

> npm i node-sass

second install:

> npm i

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass --save
```

it work for me.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.