# sass:color failing when hardcoded values work fine

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I just added sass to my create-react-app project. When I hardcode colour values, the styling is updated accordingly. But when I try to make use of some scss methods, the new styles are ignored.

e.g. This works fine...

```
:root {
  --title-blue: #2086c3;
}
```

...This does not...

```
$color-test: black !default;

:root {
  --title-blue: mix($color-test, white, 50%);
}
```

...neither does this

```
:root {
  --title-blue: $color-test
}
```

I can import the newly-renamed .scss files and all the styling remains consistent, so I don't think this is a compilation error.

Any ideas why this might be? I'm using `node-sass v4.14.1` because node sass 5 was giving me [a react error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try

```
$color-test: #000000;

:root {
    --title-blue: #{$color-test};
}
```

A couple of years ago `Sass` stopped supporting the assignment of `Sass` variables to `CSS` variables. It seems that it was never intended to support it and, it was a bug that violated the SASS language spec. Using `string interpolation` solves this problem.

You can read more about it in this Github issue of the Sass language:

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2336