# Angular Error: Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0. Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, sass

I Installing the NPM packages and after starting npm i got `node sass` error which are follows:

**Throw an Error:**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (D:\Templets\angular ecommerce side\embryoangularadmin\embryoangularadmin\Embryo-Main\embryo1\embryo\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:108:19)
    at Object.sassLoader (D:\Templets\angular ecommerce side\embryoangularadmin\embryoangularadmin\Embryo-Main\embryo1\embryo\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:20)
ERROR in ./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (D:\Templets\angular ecommerce side\embryoangularadmin\embryoangularadmin\Embryo-Main\embryo1\embryo\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:108:19)
    at Object.sassLoader (D:\Templets\angular ecommerce side\embryoangularadmin\embryoangularadmin\Embryo-Main\embryo1\embryo\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:20)
ERROR in ./src/assets/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (D:\Templets\angular ecommerce side\embryoangularadmin\embryoangularadmin\Embryo-Main\embryo1\embryo\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:108:19)
    at Object.sassLoader (D:\Templets\angular ecommerce side\embryoangularadmin\embryoangularadmin\Embryo-Main\embryo1\embryo\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:20)
```

Comment: FWIW when my upgrade to Angular 11 was complete, I no longer had node-sass in package.json. (Don't ask me how, as I upgraded from 9.x through several iterations and also tweaked things by hand.) But note also that somewhere along the way sass-loader 12.1.0 was added to package.json, too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Node Sass version 5.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's a simple version mismatch with node.**

To install the working node-sass version, you can use

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.0
```

**choose your version number** based on the following table, according to the node version you are using, which you can check by `node --version`

[image: node-sass compatibility table]

This has worked for me

Answer (score 3):

with npm =>

```
npm uninstall node-sass

npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

with yarn =>

```
yarn remove node-sass

yarn remove node-sass@4.14.1
```

**npm uninstall node-sass**

**npm install node-sass@4.14.1**

it's work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
 npm uninstall node-sass
 npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

it's work for me

Comment: Your answer is similar to accepted answer. Please add more details, or if you just want to say soome thing worked for you as same as previous answers, you can upvote given answer or add commnet.