# Try to fix this error "Node Sass version 6.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0."

Tags: reactjs, sass

I installed the latest version of node-sass in my react app but I got this error

```
"./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/index.scss)
Node Sass version 6.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0."
```

My Json file :

```
{
  "name": "new-project-to",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
```

I've checked some solutions on StackOverflow like npm install node-sass@4.14.1 but it didn't work?

What do you think guys?

Comment: have you tried exact `^4.0.0` ? `npm install node-sass@^4.0.0` ?

Comment: Yes, Amruth but it didn't work !!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0. For me, `npm uninstall node-sass; npm install sass` worked.

Answer (score 2):

Update your [sass-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader) like this: `npm i sass-loader@latest`

Comment: Did you try this? - David Jay

Answer (score 2):

Can you try editing the package.json to read

```
"dependencies": {
  "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
  ...
},
...
```

and then run `npm i`

Hope that helps, but it may not if Armuth's solution didn't work...

Comment: just tried, this one works for me ~

Answer (score 1):

updating your react-scripts to the latest version should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

updating sass using 'npm i sass-loader@latest'
and 'npm audit fix' worked for me.

Comment: you can try also (check answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0

Answer (score 1):

You must restart **npm start**
wish you luck:)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

## This worked

**To install the working node-sass version**, you can use

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

You can choose your version number based on the following table, based on the node version you are using which you can check by the command `node --version`

[image: node-sass compatibility table]

I hope it helps you