# Struggling to install SCSS in an existing React project without web-pack

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have inherited a React application that uses CSS in JS. This is cumbersome as all of the SCSS is written as a string, making it very difficult to work with as no code hinting or formating by the IDE can be done.

I am used to working with web-pack for these kinds of things, but I don't think it is part of the solution as I can't find a reference to it in the package.json file.

I am trying to switch over to SCSS, but am not quite managing. I am using the following tutorial that claims to work without web-pack:

https://medium.com/programming-sage/react-and-sass-setup-no-webpack-no-bs-a813ac56a9b7

Here is a copy of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "accelerator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.171",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.7",
    "antd": "^4.16.3",
    "apexcharts": "^3.24.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.21.3",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.6.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.7",
    "react-auth-guard": "^0.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dynamic-checkbox-tree": "^1.0.4",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-jwt": "^1.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
    "read-excel-file": "^5.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start --no-lint",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "watch:sass": "node-sass src/App.scss src/App.css -w",
    "startr": "npm-run-all — parallel start watch:sass"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1"
  }
}
```

When I run the application with the npm startr command, I get the following error:

```
> accelerator@0.1.0 startr D:\Projects\iLab\Code\Product_dashboard_Web\accelerator
> npm-run-all — parallel start watch:sass

ERROR: Task not found: "—", parallel"
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! accelerator@0.1.0 startr: `npm-run-all — parallel start watch:sass`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the accelerator@0.1.0 startr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm not sure if there is some dependency or version issue that I am not seeing, or what else the issue might be.

I'd greatly appreciate any advice anyone might have for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `startr` command is wrong,

`npm-run-all — parallel start watch:sass`

It should be,

`npm-run-all --parallel start watch:sass`

Answer (score 1):

Your project is using `react-scripts` which comes from [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). CRA uses webpack and works well with SASS.

If you want to change the default webpack configuration you will either need to [`eject`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) (not recommended) or  use something like [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) (or similar tool).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I understand your suggestion, this would incorporate web-pack in the application? I'm not looking to do that at this time, as my client does not want to make such a major change. Is there a way to implement SCSS without doing so?

Comment: My suggestion was to look at CRA docs as it already works with SASS, I don't think you need to tweak the webpack config.

Comment: After your advice, I've managed to implement the SCSS without needing to do much. I found this article that solved my original problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. :)