# Failed to compile errors

Tags: npm-install

I'm working on an Angular project. When I launch `ng serve`, the build fails as you can see below.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64626556/11719787) answer your question. Also please add more description in the question like when did you get this error? After updating angular project or any package, also try restarting your server.

Comment: Trying right now will update shortly can we sync up on a google meet or skype? I am desprate

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  You're most likely to get an answer if you include a full [mcve] *as text* showing exactly how to reproduce the issue.  See: [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the Sass module of the 6.0.1 version is not compatible with the file written for version 4.0.0

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.0.0
```

Or, using [Yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn):

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add node-sass@4.0.0
```

Comment: Build failed again
"C:\Users\Lariab Sajid\collision-report-app-master\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Lariab Sajid\collision-report-app-master\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\Users\Lariab Sajid\collision-report-app-master\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(SetTelemetryEnvironmentVariables target) ->
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.DesignTime.targets(491,5): error MSB4062:

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.DesignTime.targets(491,5): error MSB4062: The "SetEnv" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.dll. Could not load file or assembly'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the asse