# "dotnet new react" won't let me use sass files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, .net-core, sass

I tried to make an ASP.NET Core app with a react frontend, so I run the command:

```
dotnet new react -o <project name>
```

This created a project that was runnable. The problem was that it couldn't run sass files.

So I tried to install the node-sass with the "npm install node-sass" on the client folder containing the node-modules folder.

It install find. but gave me a "Node Sass version 6.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0"

I been googling this. and so far everyone been saying you need to uninstall the new version and install it running version "node-sass@4.14.1" like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0)

But it failed to install.

```html
    npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
    npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\[USER]\\Documents\\NewProject\\NewProject\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.3.0 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
    npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
    npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:195:21)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:195:21) {
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python39\python.EXE
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:326:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\[USER]\\Documents\\NewProject\\NewProject\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\NewProject\NewProject\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.3.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-18T21_41_14_265Z-debug.log
```

Hope someone can spot my mistake. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing for you to do is remove node-sass with `npm uninstall node-sass`

and then install `sass` which you can find the npm for [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) with `npm i sass --save`

I've used the `sass` library over the `node-sass` library since I had a similar problem. It has all the same stuff and works the same with React

Comment: This did the trick. don't know why, but it works. Thanks