# Problem with npm install on frontend part of project

Tags: python-3.x, npm-install, node-gyp

i get to the problem with test Project. When i try to `npm install`i get a problem bellow. I set Python2 and Python3 to the PATH and to the config to. And my `node-gyp` is 9.0.0 and i dont know why is try to build under version 3.8.0.
Project is external only from course.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\projects\\PotterAPI\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Python3" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: C:\Python3
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  C:\Python3 Error: not found: C:\Python3
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "C:\Python3". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "C:\Python3". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Python3", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\projects\\PotterAPI\\frontend\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\projects\PotterAPI\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JakubBabcanik\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-13T07_53_44_604Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0/64626556#64626556) but some extracts of this answer are:

```
1. npm uninstall node-sass
2. npm install sass
```

Or, if you are using Yarn:

```
1. yarn remove node-sass 
2. yarn add sass
```