# Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0

Tags: reactjs, node-sass, incompatibility

I've tried various commands to solve this error, But it always shows the same error. I've uninstalled node sass and installed again many times but it won't works.. Its always shows the same error..  Even I've uninstalled node modules, package.lock.json and installed again, but shows the same error again..

Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: 'node-sass' version 5.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

## Don't use `node-sass`

This is because `node-sass` has been depricated. So you will have to use the new version, which is `sass`

You can do this with

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```