# Unrecognized command error when running nux in vue project

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

When I am running `npm run dev`, I get the following error `nuxt is not a recognised command`

What should I do?
I tried deleting the old node modules file reinstalling it again clearing npm caches.

I want to run this project on my localhost. Could you help me to resolve these issues?

[and this is package. Json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kS6Z.png)]
[this error is coming when I m running npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z43Ti.png)

Comment: Have you tried to run in the command line `ngx nuxt` ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . That node-gyp runs and expectedly fails means that node and node-sass versions are mismatched. There's a plenty of related questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0

Comment: @juanmajmjr meant `npx`? And no, this is not the way to go.

Comment: It looks like NodeJS is not properly installed on your machine. I suggest re-downloading and re-installing from https://nodejs.org/en/download