# Angular - Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'

Tags: angular, node-sass

I know this issue is already discussed in few questions.
But for me the Angular application(Angular Version6) was working fine before but tried to run the same code again after few months and getting this error.
`node-sass` or `sass` is not there in my package.json.

I am not sure if this is something related to my local node version. I have tried with node16&12 but the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache, uninstall & uninstall @angular/cli

```
    npm cache clean --force
    npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
    npm install -g @angular/cli
```

If this persists, try to install the node-sass package by running the following command in your project's root directory:

```
npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52581213/15406039